# git deploy using sudo nopasswd

Tags: sudo, git

I'm trying to write simple post-recieve script, which would switch to webserver user and pull git repository. To do so, I added git user to sudoers (I've added this to very last line):

```
git ALL = (www:www) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

but I still can't execute

```
sudo -u www git pull origin production
```

without password prompt.

Comment: You are giving sudo permissions to the git user, but it sounds like you want to give sudo permissions to the `www` user, correct?  Also please run `which git` to confirm that the `git` command actually points to `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: `which git` was used to get the git path (the path is correct). Why would I want to give sudo to www user? The post-recieve script will be executed by git user and I want git user to go to webserver folder and pull changes as www user.

Comment: the command `sudo -u www git pull origin production` says to run `git pull origin production` as the www user, so it seems like you're trying to give the www user sudo access.  How come you need sudo?  How about just trying: `su -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/git pull origin production' www`.  Thats assuming your www user has a nologin shell and that your webserver folder is owned by www.

Comment: AFAIK `usera@server$~: sudo -u userb some_command` allows _usera_ run _some_command_ as _userb_. You're command does very similar thing with one difference, it requests www's password instead of git's password. I need to avoid password prompt to use it in git post-receive script

Comment: I think you're right on that.  In the sudoers file, how about trying `git ALL = (www) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git`.  In other words, remove the other www.  I suppose this specifies the group, but I'm not familiar with that construct.  Also try a simpler command like `sudo -u www /usr/bin/git` without the options and specifying the full path to be sure.  The www user may have a different PATH, so good to specify the absolute path.

Comment: the (www) part specifies which users git can sudo to. In this case it says git can do sudo -u www but can't do just sudo for example.

Comment: Well, problem solved and I fell really dumb. The password prompt triggered git not sudo. For some reason www's key was removed from git server yesterday. At least I learned a bit about sudoers file. Anyway, thanks for your support

Comment: Isn't it just easier to give the git account access (via SSH) to the remote system without password?

Comment: It would be easier, but I don't want git to have full access to www's account. I want to allow him just one command and that's exatly what the sudo is for.